# Missing Subscription Key field in Swagger API connector (trough Azure API Management) in Logic App

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, openapi

I have created a REST API with a Swagger/OPEN API specification which I will like to consume trough a Azure API Management tenant in a Logic App.

When I download the specification it looks like this:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Leasing",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "host": "ENDPOINT.azure-api.net",
  "basePath": "/leasing",
  "schemes": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "securityDefinitions": {
    "apiKeyHeader": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
      "in": "header"
    },
    "apiKeyQuery": {
      "type": "apiKey",
      "name": "subscription-key",
      "in": "query"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "apiKeyHeader": []
    },
    {
      "apiKeyQuery": []
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/{Brand}/groups": {
      "get": {
        "description": "Get a list of leasing groups on a brand",
        "operationId": "GetGroups",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Brand",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Selection of possible brands",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "Volkswagen",
              "Audi",
              "Seat",
              "Skoda",
              "VolkswagenErhverv",
              "Porsche",
              "Ducati"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Returns a list of leasing groups",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/GroupArray"
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "If the brand is not valid",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Error"
            }
          }
        },
        "produces": [
          "application/json"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Group": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "leasingModelCount": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "lowestMonthlyFee": {
          "format": "int32",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "Error": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "code": {
          "enum": [
            "NotValidBrand",
            "NotValidGroupId"
          ],
          "type": "string",
          "x-ms-enum": {
            "name": "ErrorCode",
            "modelAsString": true
          }
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "GroupArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Group"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I add this in a Logic App with the connector `HTTP + Swagger` I only get to define the {Brand} query input but not the various ways of using the Subscriptions key (header or query) as defined in `SecurityDefiniations`.

The whole `securityDefinitions` and `security` section are automatically generated in the Azure API Management service, but not recognized in Logic App.

See image of missing subscription key field:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have tried the following:

- Usage of the 'Authentication' field (but this field is limited to certain types of auths flows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#authentication)
- Change the Logic App 'Http + Swagger'-action in code to add the header parameter, but this action converts the action to a simple 'Http' action and therfore loosing the automatic schema generation from Swagger.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify this in the Authentication-field in a JSON format. Something like:

```
    { 
         "apiKeyHeader" : "your Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", 
         "apiKeyQuery" : "your subscription key" 
    }
```

Comment: If I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#authentication correctly 'Authentication' is only a limited set of authentication types (Basic, Client certificate, AAD/OAuth) and not for injected keys into the header og query.

I have read https://www.codit.eu/blog/2017/02/09/azure-api-management-and-logic-app-manage-and-get-managed/ and in these examples the keys appear as a field in the Logic App action.